# Sound on OS X doesn't work after Soundflower install

Tags: macos, audio, soundflower

Because of missing native equalizer on OS-X (Snow Leopard) I had to use third party app Soundflower in combination with AU Lab. Everything was going right, but once I restarted OS X, the sound stopped working. When I changed the volume by the keys on Macbook I hear the system sound, but in iTunes, Vimeo, some videos on YouTube, Quicktime, etc., I hear nothing.

I tried to remove Soundflower and AU Lab and reboot, but without any change.

Does anybody know how to fix this problem?

Comment: When you say you tried to remove Soundflower but without any change, do you mean that Soundflower currently is or is not installed on your system?

Comment: Under **System Preferences** » **Sound** » **Output**, what device is currently selected for sound output?

Comment: Soundflower is not installed on my system.

Comment: Internal speakers

Comment: Did you run the uninstallation script on the disk image or remove `/System/Library/Extensions/Soundflower.kext`?

Comment: Run the uninstallation script.

Comment: During a few days sound was working (iTunes and some videos on YouTube). Today after system restart sound doesn't work. I don't know with what the problem can be ...

Answer (score 2):

If you follow [this guide](http://lifehacker.com/5993636/how-to-equalize-your-computer-for-itunes-spotify-and-everything-else), you should be OK. You mentioned in the comments that you've already run the uninstall script, so perhaps you will be able to follow the guide to success. Before doing that, I would check the following:

1. Find the 'Audio MIDI Setup' utility (Applications / Audio MIDI Setup), and check all the master volume levels on your output devices.
2. If you are still passing audio through anything other than regular system audio, check all the levels and knobs and such to make sure that nothing else is turned down to 0.

NB: A common problem people have with Soundflower is the [master volume being set to 0 by default](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/116062/65995).

**If none of that is the issue**, and you follow the guide, you could try my setup, which is like this:

• Go find AU Lab 2.3, and 
• Update your Soundflower to 1.6.7 with [this fix, available on Github](https://github.com/crmne/Soundflower/releases). It has worked for me on Mavericks 10.9.4, it prevents an obnoxious clicking sound as well, and it gives you master faders for Soundflower outputs in the Soundflowerbed dropdown.

NB: **If you are not on Mavericks** you may not need the updated versions of everything.

Comment: I am seeing that master volume issue, but for some reason the Master Volume slider is greyed out...I can't move it to be above 0.

Comment: FWIW, I now use SoundSource from RogueAmoeba. Still gives you access to your AU Lab plugins, so my EQ settings didn't have to change but I did have to set it up again. In my mind, 100% worth the money. Works flawlessly, and includes more features that I enjoy.

Answer (score -1):

The only way I've found to fix this is to add new user accout and use it instead of the old one.

Comment: That is the way I dont wanna go :(